# Update an embed whenever another bot's embed edits

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So there's a bot that sends an embed to a specific channel and edits it time a time with new info.

And I need to have an embed in another channel that basically replicates that bot embed, and when the bot updates its embed I need to update mine too but only changing the title.

I only come to this, but I'm not sure how to do this, I'll appreciate some help.

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.channel.id === "809470058173562960") {
        if (!message.author.bot || !message.embeds[0]) return;

        const receivedEmbed = message.embeds[0];
        const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed(receivedEmbed).setTitle("New title");

        client.channels.fetch(809470016486375444).then((channel) => {
            channel.send(exampleEmbed);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Just thought might be a better idea to do it with messageUpdate so I made this so far, still ill appreciate some help                                   ```
client.on('messageUpdate', (oldMessage, newMessage) => {
if (message.channel.id === "809470058173562960") {

const edittedEmbed = message.embeds[0];
        const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed(edittedEmbed)

client.channels.fetch(809470016486375444).then((channel) => {
            channel.send(newEmbed);
        });
} 
}`